# DRF social authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth

Im implementing drf social oauth2 and while accessing the URL - `localhost:8000/auth/login/facebook/` I get `'drf' is not a registered namespace`,  `No ReverseMatch` error and when I change my `namespace`  to  `social`, I get `'social' is not a registered namespace`.

#URLPatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('drf_social_oauth2.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('api/', include("users.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

#Installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    # rest
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",

    # Oauth
    "oauth2_provider",
    "social_django",
    "drf_social_oauth2",

    # apps
    "accounts",
    "inventory",
    "cart",
    "orders",
    "users",

]
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Did you add all the settings included in the documentation? That is TEMPLATES, REST_FRAMEWORK, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, etc.

Comment: yes I have add all the things in that django social oauth2 git repo.  Im using django 4

Answer (score 2):

Below solution works for me:
by providing below URL to urlpatterns:

`path('o/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))`

```
 urlpatterns = [
 path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
 path('auth/', include('drf_social_oauth2.urls', namespace='drf')),
 path('o/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
 path('api/', include("users.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and hit below URL:

`localhost:8000/o/login/facebook/`

Comment: why adding  path('o/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
could you please explain??

Comment: When using drf-social-oauth2, adding path('o/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')) to your Django project's urls.py file is necessary because this line defines the endpoints that handle OAuth2 authentication for social providers.

OAuth2 is an open-standard authorization protocol that is widely used for third-party authentication. It allows users to grant access to their social media accounts to a third-party application without sharing their login credentials.